# Change password form while session is deleted

Tags: python, django

Periodically, I force some users to log out (because their passwords have to be changed) and for that I delete their Session cookie. What's happening next is that these users are redirected to the login screen.

How could I implement their redirection to a template that the only thing they can do is to change their password?

Nikos

Comment: Don't delete the cookie? That causes the server to lose all state. Set a session variable that says the user's password has expired and needs changing instead.

Answer (score 1):

The approach what you are following is not correct.

If you want to force the user to change the password, set the flag and if flag is true redirect the user to change the password.

If you kill the user will be redirected to login page by default in any web application.

Thanks.